# How do I get the selected value from a select option?

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I'm unable to get the selected value from a select option list and I can't figure out why. Here is the code I have so far:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="time_number"
    ng-init="time_number = task.time_numbers[0]"
    ng-options="number as number.num for number in task.time_numbers">
</select>

<div ng-click="save()">Save</div>
```

Inside Controller:

```
var scope = $rootScope;

var task = {
        time_numbers : [{num: 1}, {num: 2}, {num: 3}, {num: 4}, {num: 5}, {num: 6}, {num: 7}],
    };

scope.task = task;

scope.save = function() {
    console.log('time_number = ' + scope.time_number);
}
```

The console always displays `time_number = undefined`. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Also avoid using `$rootScope`.

```
console.log('time_number = ' + scope.time_number.num);
```

Since your model is bind to number it returns an object.

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nxGMrfQTPrcGBXhMVqIr)**

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. The console is displaying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'num' of undefined". Also, why should I avoid using ``$rootScope``?